# While vs. for: what is the best?

Tags: c, for-loop, while-loop, cycle

If I can do a cycle with for and while both, which should I choose?

**[for]**

```
int num = 10;
int i;

for (i=0; i<num; i++)
{
    /* ... */
}
```

**[while]**

```
int num = 10;
int i = num;

while ( i-- )
{
    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: The latter won’t ever end without a break.

Comment: Neither. Use for (int i=0; i<num; i++)

Comment: Define best....Best for speed?for memory?

Comment: _@David Heffernan_. GCC give me this error: `error: ‘for’ loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 mode`

Comment: _@laaposto_. Speed, memory, standard..

Comment: @user: add the GCC flag `-std=c99` to your compile command to use the C99 standard.

Comment: @user you have to put the int declaration outside the for in 'old' C

Comment: But why should I use a thing of the old standard?

Comment: @user It is you that is choosing to use a 25 year old standard!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I not understand... C11 is the last standard!

Comment: Indeed. So why are you using a C89 compiler?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I did not know: I noticed now! Why GCC default uses C89?

Comment: Anyway, the answer is still to use neither of the options in the Q!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The choice between `for` and `while` is just matter of clarity:

K&R . Chapter 1. The For statment:

> The choice between while and for is arbitrary, based on which seems
>       clearer. The for is usually appropriate for loops in which the initialization and
>       increment are single statements and logically related, since it is more compact
>       than while and it keeps the loop control statements together in one place.

Answer (score 2):

Performance, of course, depends on the implementation in the language used. However, in most cases and with most compilers, the generated code from both loops will pretty much be the same.

A rule of thumb would be to use `while` when you don't know exactly how many times you want to iterate. In your example, it doesn't make much difference. Use what's clearer to you.

And yes, declarations in the `for` loop are only allowed in newer versions of C (C99).

Comment: Most CPU's these days have some kind of vector processing assembly instructions available. It is much much simpler for a compiler to turn for loops into vector instructions than while loops. For num = 10, it probably is a wash but for larger arrays, it can be a signficant win.

Answer (score 2):

Usually, you'd use a `for` loop for something like that because you know **before** you start the loop how many times you need the loop to run. `while` loops are more for when you don't know how many times you're going to have to repeat, and something that the user inputs or some random `int` will change it

Comment: So for your case, I'd use a for loop

Answer (score 0):

In the example above, you should use a for loop since it clearly expresses the intent of what you intend. "Do this loop num times". Also, it is much simpler for the compiler to potentially optimize for loops into vector assembly operations.

You should use a while loop when you have a clearly expressible condition like
"Read lines until EOF" or some other condition that doesn't have an easily enumerable solution.

Also, I consider it poor practice to depend on the fact that 0 is false. You should clearly write the condition that exits the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Every program solve in while loop that can be solved in for loop,but for loop suitable for:-
1--> If i know  how many time the loop Will execute and while loop is suitable for if i don't know how many time the loop will be executed.

Comment: this answer may be more of a comment??